# Converting an if/else block with True/False statements into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am iterating through characters in a string, and I want to determine the type of each character.

This can be done with an if/else block:

```
    if char.isdigit():
        char_type = 'number'
    elif char.isalpha():
        char_type = 'letter'
    elif char in {'*', '/', '+', '-', '='}:
        char_type = 'operator'
    else:
        char_type = 'other'
```

If the code was something like this:

```
    if val == 1:
        char_type = 'number'
    elif val == 2:
        char_type = 'letter'
    elif val == 3:
        char_type = 'operator'
```

The dictionary could be:

```
d = {1: 'number', 2: 'letter', 3: 'operator'}
```

But in this case, each of the statements is either `True` or `False`. Can this be converted into a dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the keys to be. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @JETM Probably something like `char_type = d[char]` instead of the `if` statements.

Comment: honesty, just wrap it in function and call `char_type(char)`. There is no readibility saving at all comparing to `char_type[char]`, and you'll just confuse people that read your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `d[char]` syntax, but it hardly sees worth the cost in complexity and readability.

You could encapsulate your `if/else` in the `__getitem__` method of a class, and then use `[]` syntax to retrieve the character type, like so:

```
class CharType:
    def __getitem__(self, char):
        if char.isdigit():
            char_type = 'number'
        elif char.isalpha():
            char_type = 'letter'
        elif char in {'*', '/', '+', '-', '='}:
            char_type = 'operator'
        else:
            char_type = 'other'
        return char_type

d = CharType()

print(d["a"], d["+"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can setup a dictionary to do all the work.  Once setup, you can run lots of text through it very quickly:

```
import string

type_dictionary = dict()
type_dictionary.update({c: 'letter' for c in string.ascii_letters})
type_dictionary.update({c: 'number' for c in string.digits})
type_dictionary.update({c: 'operator' for c in {'*', '/', '+', '-', '='}})

string = "elif val == 3:"

for character in string:
    print(character, "->", type_dictionary.get(character, 'other'))
```

OUTPUT

```
e -> letter
l -> letter
i -> letter
f -> letter
  -> other
v -> letter
a -> letter
l -> letter
  -> other
= -> operator
= -> operator
  -> other
3 -> number
: -> other
```

An alternate approach is to use a character translation table:

```
import string
import itertools

type_dictionary = {'1': 'number', '2': 'letter', '3': 'operator', '4': 'other'}

maketrans_dictionary = dict({c: '4' for c in string.printable})
maketrans_dictionary.update({c: '2' for c in string.ascii_letters})
maketrans_dictionary.update({c: '1' for c in string.digits})
maketrans_dictionary.update({c: '3' for c in {'*', '/', '+', '-', '='}})

table = str.maketrans(maketrans_dictionary)

string = "elif val == 3:"

for character, character_type in zip(string, string.translate(table)):
    print(character, "->", type_dictionary[character_type])
```

Neither of the above is Unicode-friendly, without additional work, but I'm assuming that isn't an issue as neither is `char in {'*', '/', '+', '-', '='}`.

Comment: Won't this fail for "ñ"?

Comment: No, @Robᵩ, it prints "ñ -> other".

Comment: But it *should* print "ñ -> letter", to match the intent of OP's original code.

Comment: I understand @Robᵩ, just like your solution fails for the Unicode multiplication operator, ×, returning 'other' instead of 'operator'.

Answer (score -1):

According to what I understood by your question.

```
s="abcd12e+"
dic={}
for i in s:
    if i.isdigit():
        dic[i]="digit"
    elif i.isalpha():
        dic[i]="alpha"
    elif i in ['*', '/', '+', '-', '=']:
        dic[i]="operator"
    else:
        dic[i]="other"
print dic
```

for the example string output be :
{'a': 'alpha', 'c': 'alpha', 'b': 'alpha', 'e': 'alpha', 'd': 'alpha', '+': 'operator', '1': 'digit', '2': 'digit'}